# HOW TO CALCULATE DIFFERENCE IN MONTHS SQL DB2

Tags: sql, datetime, db2

I have a variable CREATION_DATE in numeric format "202101" indicating year and month, I need to calculate the difference in months between that date and Current date, I have tried:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(CREATION_DATE),'YYYYMM')),
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(
    YEAR(CURRENT DATE)*100+MONTH(CURRENT DATE)),
    'YYYYMM'
  )))
```

and this:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(CREATION_DATE),'YYYYMM')),
  CURRENT DATE
)
```

Comment: And what was / is the problem?

Comment: It depends on how you are going to calculate it. Suppose you have YYYYMM, and the expression could be: `(YEAR (CURRENT DATE) - YYYY) * 12 + MONTH (CURRENT DATE) - MM`. Would it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this:

```
WITH temp(creation_date) AS (VALUES ('202102')
)
SELECT creation_date
     , CURRENT date
     , months_between(CURRENT date, DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(CREATION_DATE),'YYYYMM')))
FROM temp
```